# ListItemButton text won’t align

Tags: python, kivy

I’ve been trying to align the text of my ListitemButton but I’ve been finding it challenging. I’m following the documentation but still not working below is my code

```
class CountryListButton(ListItemButton):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CountryListButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.halign = "left"
        self.valign = "middle"
        self.text_size = self.size
        self.color = [0, 0, 0, 1]
        self.font_size = 15
        self.font_name = "fonts/Qanelas-Light.otf"
        self.selected_color = [1, 1, 1, 1]
        self.selected_background_normal = ""
        self.deselected_color = [1, 1, 1, 1]
        self.deselected_background_normal = ""
        self.background_color = [1, 1, 1, 1]
        self.background_normal = ""
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's all about your text.size property which you have set to the size of containing widget. So Kivy can't change it's position because it fills all parent widget. Try to reduce text.size, maybe it'll help.